# Why does my auth break when I store JWTs in cookies versus passing JWT in via headers?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, jwt

I have authentication setup on Express using PassportJS and JWTs. Authentication works properly when I pass the JWT in via the header, but when I try extracting the JWT from a cookie, authentication fails and the `verify` function that's declared when configuring my passport JWT strategy never gets called.

I've verified that the `cookieExtractor` function is working properly (the function is taken directly from [passport-jwt documentation](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt#writing-a-custom-extractor-function).

Here's the code *(I've only included the relevant code here but I'd be happy to share the full code if necessary):*

**app.js** *(Server configuration)*

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
var passport = require('passport');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Routes
var index = require('./routes/index');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var dashboard = require('./routes/dashboard');

// Database
var config = require('./config/default.json');
var User = require('./models/user');
mongoose.connect(config.database);

var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);

module.exports = app;
```

**routes/index.js** *(Creating route)*

```
...
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false, failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res) {
  res.send('Yay, it worked.');
});
...
```

**config/passport.js** *(Configuring passport)*

```
...
// `cookieExtractor` returns the correct token (I verified this by logging out the token it was returning)
var cookieExtractor = function(req) {
    var token = null;
    if (req && req.cookies) token = req.cookies.token;
    return token;
};

module.exports = function(passport) {
  var opts = {};
  // Note: Authentication works when I pass the JWT in via headers, but auth fails when attempting to pass JWT via cookies
  // opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
  opts.jwtFromRequest = cookieExtractor;
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;

  // Local authentication using JWT's
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    // Note: This function works as expected and returns the user from the database
    // when passing JWT via headers, but it does not get invoked when passing JWT
    // via cookies. I've verified that the JWT is getting extracted properly
    // from the cookie
    User.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload._doc._id }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      }
      if (user) {
        done(null, user);
      } else {
        done(null, false);
      }
    });
  }));
};
```

### UPDATE

After some digging around in the `jsonwebtoken` module, it seems that the token is not being decoded. Inside the `jsonwebtoken` module in `index.js`, on line 195 when it uses `jws` to decode the JWT token, nothing happens. Here's the code snippet from that file along with some comments I added:

```
JWT.verify = function(jwtString, secretOrPublicKey, options, callback) {

...

  var decodedToken;

  try {
    // 'decodedToken' is null after running the following line
    // Have verified that 'jwtString' exists and is a JWT
    decodedToken = jws.decode(jwtString);
  } catch(err) {
    return done(new JsonWebTokenError('invalid token'));
  }

  if (!decodedToken) {
    // The program ends here because 'decodedToken' is null
    return done(new JsonWebTokenError('invalid token'));
  }

...

}
```

Comment: can you include the code that loads all of the express middleware that you're using? i'm curious where and how you configure the cookie parser middleware.

Comment: your verify callback takes `req` as input argument, but I don't see `passReqToCallback` in `opts` which would give you that req object.

Comment: @hassansin Thanks for pointing that out, I had `passReqToCallback` in `opts` initially but took it out as I was copying and pasting the code from my app into SO. Have cleaned it up in my original post to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @aembke Updated post with all of the middleware I'm using including how I'm initializing `cookieParser`. For what it's worth I used `express-generator` (yeoman) for the scaffolding.

Comment: @aembke Updated my post with some additional information after some digging around. It appears that the token is never getting decoded.

Comment: which version of `passport-jwt` are you using?

Comment: @aembke I figured out what the issue was after diving into the `jsonwebtoken` module and then the `jws` module in my efforts to debug this issue. It turns out that the JWT I was trying to decode actually had the authorization type prepended to the token I was attempting to decode (`JWT`) and that's why the token was not being decoded properly. Once I took out the type, everything worked.